# Android EditText - Editable but not Selectable?

Tags: android, android-edittext, touch-event, selectable

Is it possible to make an EditText editable but not selectable? I want to be able to edit a bit of text, then drag it around the page. It works but while you're dragging it, that counts as a long click, so it selects some of the text.

Will I have to do something like make another view appear when I click on the EditText, have that capture the touch events instead, then hide it when the event action is up and return focus to the editText? That seems hacky/overly complicated.

Comment: Did you try returning true from your onLongClick event in your listener so that the event doesn't continue on to the default onLongClickListener for the EditText?

Comment: It's not a long click event, it's a touch event, but the TextView class has an inherent longclicklistener.
I tried telling it to return true for ACTION_DOWN, but then it just moves the edittext, and it doesn't go to edit mode or pull up the keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a slightly less hacky solution than the one I mentioned above, and then tried (and it didn't work), but this does work:

first do this,

```
image_text.cancelLongPress();
```

which apparently cancels any inherited click, not just the long click, i.e. it shows the cursor, and it doesn't select any text, but it also doesn't bring up the keyboard, but that's easy:

```
View v = activity.getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
        if (v != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(v, 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Achieved desired behavior using `setTextIsSelectable(false)`. The trick was to run `setTextIsSelectable(true)` first. It overcomes the bug/feature in the SDK (debug this method if you interested in). Tested on Android 7.1.1.

```
editText.setTextIsSelectable(true); // needed in order to next line work properly
editText.setTextIsSelectable(false);

// restore soft keyboard functionality broken by previous line
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editText.setFocusable(true);
editText.setClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:`android:textIsSelectable="false"`

2nd possible solution would be to put empty onLongClickListener that would consume event.

```
OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {\
        return true; //true = event consumed, false = event not consumed
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't work, something is overriding it.
I did it in the xml AND programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly the solution you are looking for, but when the `EditText` is dropped into place, you could ensure there is no selection by calling `editText.clearFocus();`

This would be an issue if you needed to retain selection that was existing prior to dragging, but not if you just wanted to ensure the selection was cleared.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
myEditText.setTextIsSelectable(false);
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer?

Comment: I would have thought it was self-explanatory. You could use it for example in the onCreate() method of your activity. The first line retrieves the EditText and the second makes it not selectable on long press, although a double tap will still work. The advantage over Vladimir's suggestion (using android:textIsSelectable="false" in your xml) is if you want to be able to toggle the property on and off.

Comment: the explanation is not for me. I recommended because your answer was flagged as Low Quality and you can explain your answer will be better for any user looking to solve maybe a problem like it.

Comment: I tried that. You'd think that would do it, but that didn't work in my case.